# Sort char pointer array in C

Tags: c, sorting, char

I am trying to sort array of char pointers, for that purpose I use `qsort` function, but I can't understand what I am doing wrong and how I can sort that array.

```
int StringCompare( const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char const *char_a = (char const *)a;
    char const *char_b = (char const *)b;

    return strcmp(char_a, char_b);
}

int main() {
    char *a[] = { "Garima",
          "Amit",
          "Gaurav",
          "Vaibhav"
        };

    int n;

    qsort( a, 4, sizeof(char*), StringCompare);
    for (n=0; n<4; n++)
        printf ("%c ",*a[n]);
}
```

**The Output is**: G A G V

Comment: strcmp doesn't do what you think it does: Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: `a` should be an array of `const char *`, since they're unmodifiable.

Comment: @chris and if I want to sort char array what must I do ?

Comment: You are sorting an array of pointers, so the compare function should expect two pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the values passed to the sort function (a.k.a `StringCompare`) are pointers into the `a` array. In other words, they are of type `const char **`.

You need to instead declare `char_a` and `char_b` as `const char **`, and dereference them in the call to `strcmp`:

```
int StringCompare( const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char const **char_a = a;
    char const **char_b = b;

    return strcmp(*char_a, *char_b);
}
```

Also note the casts are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

proper comparator:

```
int StringCompare( const void* a, const void* b)
{ 
char const *char_a = *(char const **)a;
char const *char_b = *(char const **)b;

return strcmp(char_a, char_b);
}
```

NOTE:

according to sort description comparator function is:

```
compar
Pointer to a function that compares two elements.
This function is called repeatedly by qsort to compare two elements. 
It shall follow the       following prototype:

int compar (const void* p1, const void* p2);
```

so, it receives not a char*, but char**

proper output cycle:

```
for (n=0; n<4; n++)
    printf ("%s ", a[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your StringCompare function this way:

```
int StringCompare(const char **a, const char **b)
{
    return strcmp(*a, *b);
}
```

No need to clutter the code with explicit casting because you can implicitly cast a void pointer to any other pointer type.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort char-arrays for the first letters, you could implement a function, that looks at the (unsigned) values of the first char in the array. As they are all equal to the numbers in the ASCII-standards. But you have to be careful if you mix upper case chars with lower case chars.

I know... its not a some special implemented function, but I once programmed it that way and it worked.